# Display data in text boxes by clicking into DataGridview to update or save the data C# with MySql db

Tags: c#

I want to display the data into the text boxes to update the data(is this because of the DateTimePicker?. This is my code.

```
private void btnUpdate_Click
cmd = new MySqlCommand("UDPATE tbl_members SET .......", con);
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@memberid", memberid);
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("Birthdate", dtpBDate.Text);
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@DateofMembership", dtpMembership.Text);
cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
MessageBox.Show("Record Updated Successfully");
con.Close();
DisplayData();
ClearData();

private void dgv_Member_RowHeadMouseClick
memberid = Convert.ToInt32(dgv_Member.Rows[e.RowIndex].Cells[0].Value.ToString());
dtpBDate.Text = dgv_Member.Rows[e.RowIndex].Cells[12].Value.ToString();
dtpMembership.Text = dgv_Member.Rows[e.RowIndex].Cells[22].Value.ToString();
```

But I got this error "String was not recognized as a valid DateTime"

Comment: Change `dtpBDate.Text` to `dtpBDate.Value`

Comment: when I change dtpBDate.Text to dtpBdate.Value. I got red lines sir. it means that it is an error.

Comment: Still got this error sir "String was not recognized as a valid DateTime".

Comment: I already change them both sir. but still got the same error.

Comment: If your grid is storing a datetime `dtpBDate.Value = (DateTime)dgv_Member.Rows[e.RowIndex].Cells[12].Value;`

Comment: If your grid is storing a string `dtpBDate.Value = DateTime.ParseExact(dgv_Member.Rows[e.RowIndex].Cells[12].Value, "your date format here", PutSomeSuitableCultureInfoHere);`

Comment: This is all hugely easier if your grid is databinded to a data table that has a datetime column.. you just bind the picker and the grid through the same binding source and then any row you click on in the grid is automatically put to the text boxes etc

Comment: If you don't know whether your grid is storing a string or datetime, show the code that populates the grid

Comment: I try to use this code sir `dtpBDate.Value = (DateTime)dgv_Member.Rows[e.RowIndex].Cells[12].Value;` but i got this error " specified cast is not valid "

Comment: what code should I put sir dtpBDate.Value = DateTime.ParseExact(dgv_Member.Rows[e.RowIndex].Cells[12].Value, "your date format here", PutSomeSuitableCultureInfoHere); "PutSomeSuitableCultureInfoHere"?

Comment: Show the code that puts the value in the cell

Comment: I think this code have a error sir, because when I try to comment the other code, their is no problem to save the data. private void dgv_Member_RowHeadMouseClick(object sender, IDataGridViewCellMouseEventArgs e)
memberid = Convert.ToInt32(dgv_Member.Rows[e.RowIndex].Cells[0].Value.ToString());
dtpBDate.Text = dgv_Member.Rows[e.RowIndex].Cells[12].Value.ToString();
dtpMembership.Text = dgv_Member.Rows[e.RowIndex].Cells[22].Value.ToString(); that is why when I select one data to update the information, I've got this error "String was not recognized as a valid DateTime"

Comment: private void DisplayData()
        {
            
            con.Open();
            DataTable dt = new DataTable();
            dataAdapter = new MySqlDataAdapter("select * from tbl_members", con);
            dataAdapter.Fill(dt);
            dgv_Member.DataSource = dt;
            con.Close();
        }

Comment: private void AddNewMember_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {

            dataAdapter = new MySqlDataAdapter("Select * from tbl_members", "server=127.0.0.1;uid=root;pwd=;database=membersregistry_db; Convert Zero Datetime=True");
            DataSet ds = new DataSet();
            dataAdapter.Fill(ds, "tbl_members");
            dgv_Member.DataSource = ds.Tables["tbl_members"].DefaultView;
        }

Comment: private void dgv_Member_CellContentClick(object sender, DataGridViewCellEventArgs e)
        {
           
            con.Open();
            DataTable dt = new DataTable();
            dataAdapter = new MySqlDataAdapter("select * from tbl_members", con);
            dataAdapter.Fill(dt);
            dgv_Member.DataSource = dt;
            con.Close();
        }

Comment: Please don't put code in comments; hit EDIT on the question and edit it into there so it can be formatted nicely

Comment: Also show the table definition in the database